# How to use Cspell --file-list stdin

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, spawn

I wanted to use cspell --file-list command as a child process in Node Js.
I wanted to pass large array of strings to this child process and feed it by stdin.

var child = spawn('cspell --file-list',[], {shell:true});

Now I wanted to pass strings one by one to this child process.

Can someone help me in this with small example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

send files as an argument:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const cmd = 'cspell';

const checkFiles = (files) => {

    const proc = spawn(cmd, ['--file-list'].concat(files), {shell: true });

    const buffers = [];

    proc.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => buffers.push(chunk));

    proc.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.error(`stderr: ${data.toString()}`);
    });

    proc.stdout.on('end', () => {
        const result = (Buffer.concat(buffers)).toString();
        console.log(`done, result:\n${result}`);

    });

};

// pass files array
checkFiles(['some-file', 'another-file']);
```

Comment: Problem with this is if I have 100 files then it call spawn 100 times.
I need to pass all 100 files at once using  "cspell --file-list stdin"

Comment: you said a single string... check the updated code

Comment: I am not sure why it is calling

proc.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.error(`stderr: ${data.toString()}`);
    });

and not

proc.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => buffers.push(chunk));

even though application is exiting with code 0.

Comment: that's probably cspell throwing some error, which is why it's in `stderr`